# Where do I find alias arguments in fastlane?

Tags: fastlane

In a fastlane project that I am taking over everything is run by command line (e.g. not fastfile). In this project (using fastlane 1.7) there are aliases used for arguments. Where would I go to find out what each of the aliases map to as far as fastlane commands? For example:

```
def build(Myapp, skip_profile)
  if skip_profile || download_provisioning_profiles(MyApp)
    build_cmd = "gym -a -r -s #{MyApp.name} -o ./build -n #{MyApp.ipa_name} --use_legacy_build_api"
    system(build_cmd)
  else
    puts "Was unable to install provisioning profiles"
    exit 1
  end
end
```

Looking at this I am pretty sure that -o is the output but where would I look to find out explicitly what -a and -r and -s and -o are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

`fastlane gym --help`

to get a list of all available options for the gym tool.